# send variable to another page via hyperlink and select it in <select> tag (HTML, Jquery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 2 pages cpu and mobo. I have a MySQL databse table named cpu, this table is displayed on cpu page, i want the user to click on a cpu table row and a hyperlink to take them to mobo page where the cpu selected is selected in the  tag to filter motherboards.

## CPU page

### Table:

[Image](https://imgur.com/a/1UOryUo)

Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, price, id, mark, value, url, socket FROM cpu";
$result = $connection->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table id='myTable'><thead><tr><th>CPU</th><th>Price</th><th>Mark</th><th>Value</th><th>Socket</th><th>Image</th></tr></thead>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tbody><tr><td><a href='https://au.pcpartpicker.com/product/".$row["id"]."' target='_blank'>" . $row["name"]. "</a></td><td>" . $row["price"]."</td><td>" . $row["mark"]."</td><td>" . $row["value"]."</td><td>" . $row["socket"]."</td><td><img src=". $row["url"]." height='42' width='42'></td></tr></tbody>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

## Motherboard page

### Table:

[Image](https://imgur.com/7cmWv7p)

Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, price, id, socket, ramslots, maxram, chipset FROM motherboard";
$result = $connection->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table id='myTable'><thead><tr><th>Motherboard</th><th>Price</th><th>Socket</th><th>Chipset</th><th>Ram Slots</th><th>Max Ram</th></tr></thead>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tbody><tr data-socket='". $row['socket'] . "'><td><a href='https://au.pcpartpicker.com/product/" . $row["id"] . "' target='_blank'>" . $row["name"] . "</a></td><td>" . $row["price"] . "</td><td>" . $row["socket"] . "</td><td>" . $row["chipset"] . "</td><td>" . $row["ramslots"] . "</td><td>" . $row["maxram"] . "</td></tr></tbody>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

### Select:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgqLH.jpg)

Code (PHP):

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<select name='CPUmenu'>";
    echo "<option value=''>CPU</option>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value='". $row["socket"] . "'>".$row["name"]."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Code (Jquery):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
        $('select[name="CPUmenu"]').change(function(e) {
          let socket = $(this).val();
          $('tbody tr[data-socket]').show();
          if (socket.length) {
            $('tbody tr[data-socket!="' + socket + '"]').hide();
          }
        });
    });
});
```

## Expected result:

I need to change the hyperlink of each cpu row to link to mobo.php and send the cpu name along with it in url. On mobo i need the sent url to be selected from the  group automatically

If you need any more details please ask.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with the following code:

```
echo "<tbody><tr><td><a href='mobo.php?cpu_name=".$row["name"]."' target='_blank'>" . $row["name"]. "</a></td><td>" . $row["price"]."</td><td>" . $row["mark"]."</td><td>" . $row["value"]."</td><td>" . $row["socket"]."</td><td><img src=". $row["url"]." height='42' width='42'></td></tr></tbody>";
```

And

```
if(isset($_GET['cpu_name'])){
  $namehref = $_GET['cpu_name']; //some_value
}
```

And

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row["name"] == $namehref) {
        echo "<option value='". $row["socket"] . "' selected>".$row["name"]."</option>";    
        } else {
        echo "<option value='". $row["socket"] . "'>".$row["name"]."</option>";
        }
    }
```